# How to disable anchor element on load using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my project , there is one anchor element as follows.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="<?php if ($logged_uid == 0) { ?>login('mystudyplus','free','topicid8:41');$('#login_msg').show();<?php } else { ?>addtodashboard('mystudyplus','free','topicid8:41');<?php } ?>" class="btndownld" style="margin-left:120px;margin-top:200px;background:#f60098;">TRY NOW</a>
```

I just want to disable the above anchor element when page completely loads. Actully I have used removeattr property of jquery. But I only want to disable the anchor element  without removing onClick() event. So please help me in this question.

Comment: Why do you want to retain the `onclick` attribute?

Comment: If you would like to disable your attribute defined event handler you have to either 1: change it or 2: remove it on load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you'd like to keep your existing attribute handler. I suppose you're talking about handler definition, but not its processing, because that's what you're trying to prevent.

### Solution 1: remove attribute completely

```
$(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        $("a").removeAttr("onclick");
    });
});
```

### Solution 2: change attribute code

```
$(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        var link = $("a");
        var existing = link.attr("onclick");
        link.attr("onclick", "return;" + existing);
    });
});
```

### Solution 3: change attribute but store definition

```
$(function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        var link = $("a");
        var existing = link.attr("onclick");
        link.attr("data-onclick", existing)
            .removeAttr("onclick");
    });
});
```

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E6ALE/2) shows all three solutions. I've written it so that it doesn't change links on page load but rather simulates page load by clicking a link. Click any of the first three links first then simulate page load and click any link again and you'll see that all of them work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

**Using CSS**

```
a{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Dynamically using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('a').css('pointer-events','none');

});
```

Comment: `.prop("disabled", true);`  ;)

Comment: This also won't disable existing attribute-defined event handler.

Answer (score -2):

write script like below

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("a").removeAttr("onclick");
});
```

Comment: This will only prevent event propagation and default HREF functionality that in this case does nothing as it defines javascript functionality. See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZcR5n/) as a proof.